# How to hide the pop up for my application?

Tags: android, popup

Have a look on the below pic

[image]

The foreground pop up is handsent sms app.The back ground is my app. My problem is whenever an sms received popup window opens.The bad thing is even my app runs .Their pop up box may disturb my app users.How can block their pop up on my screens. The dafault sms app is opened then handsent sms app wont show popup on the window.Like that I also want to block other popup on my app screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Their pop up box may disturb my app users..How can block their pop up on my screens

You don't know that. This is not something you should try to control, if the user has an app that pops up, that is probably their preference. Your app should however be prepared for interruptions, i.e handle your app's [lifecycle properly](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: But default sms app block the handsent pop on their window..Like that I also want  to block

Comment: @sarath It doesn't block handcent, the messaging app handles the broadcast for a recieved message and marks the message as `seen` (not read). remember that since the app is already running, it could possibly mark the message as `seen` even before handling the broadcast. handcent will still receive the broadcast but check the database for `unseen` messages and find none and therefore not bring up a pop-up.

Comment: So..my app also sms app.So..If my app is opened ,then i will first get result. How can I mark messages seen before handsent handles them.

Comment: @sarath one way is to have a [Content Observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) that listens for changes in the mms/sms database, in the content observer's `onChange` callback, mark everything as seen, by changing the `seen` column to `1`, this will only work if your app is currently running. if you try and do this by waiting for a broadcast, you are not guaranteed to receive it 1st, or even receive it (the broadcast) at all if another 3rd party sms app is installed.

Comment: @wikki.. If both handsent and gosms is installed then my apps notification also missing..:(..Is there any way to get priority to my app??

Comment: Hi @Wikki..I set android:priority..So now i am getting nottification with handsent and gosms..no I have to handle that popup issue too..thanks for the help brother

Comment: gosms sets its priority to 2147483647, which is the largest possible `int`, you can set yours to this by adding `android:priority="2147483647"` to your intent, but like i said it is not guaranteed that you'll receive the broadcast as gosms might abort it. however, note that its not common for a user to want to receive 2 or more notifications for the same sms from different apps. they'll tend to turn off notifications for all but one sms app, if at all they have many.

Comment: you shouldn't worry much about whether you receive the broadcast 1st or last, just set the priority to 999 which is the maximum advised by android devs, and let the user decide which app he/she wants to handle notifications, of course this means that you allow them to turn notifications for your app as well.

Comment: i haven't done proper testing on the two but android documentation advises using between -999 and 999. i'd go with 999, going beyond this is said to have unpredictable results.